# Redirect to a different website by apache config

Tags: apache, server, devops

We are running a node application by reverse proxy. Here is our apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abc.com

    Alias /blog/bn /var/www/website/dist/blog/bn
    Alias /blog /var/www/website/dist/blog

    <Directory /var/www/website/dist/blog/bn>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/website/dist/blog>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(blog|blog/bn) !

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

> Here we are also running other 2 blogs (**blog & blog/bn**) and url
>   those applications are:
>
> - abc.com/blog
> - abc.com/blog/bn

Now we are running a new application called: **business.com**, But we want to redirect from **abc.com/example**

So we wrote a rule:

```
ProxyPassMatch /example https://example.com
ProxyPassReverse /example https://example.com
```

Bu it doesn't work. So how could we redirect by apache?

Comment: Is your application running on `https://business.com`?

Comment: it's a dummy url, its use as example

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com)

Comment: You can use `ProxyPass /example https://business.com/
ProxyPassReverse /example https://business.com/`